# My Nexus 5 (5.0, stock, rooted) won't boot, despite being on 70% charge when I last checked. What can I do?

Tags: nexus-5, boot-loop, 5.0-lollipop

When plugged in, it kept repeating the Google logo, shutting off, and repeating. I unplugged, and now it won't turn on at all, no matter what combination of power and volume buttons I try (even recovery mode-- trust me, I've tried it all). I've been running Lollipop for over a week now with no hitches, and this came out of nowhere. Any suggestions to get me out of this?

Comment: Check the battery connection to make sure it's secure. Movement and jostling can sometimes can loosen the connection.

Comment: My nexus 7 did the same thing 2 days ago. I opened the case and the connection was partially separated. Plugged it back correctly and bootloop is gone. Working perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably soft-bricked. Use a program called Nexus Root Toolkit to reinstall the stock ROM: http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/